# How to call a Jboss BRMS Rule from Rest Client

Tags: web-services, rest, jboss, rules

I have created a Rule using a decision table in Jboss BRMS and deployed as a REST service using the kie-server. But can't find how to pass parameters to the service.

When I create a Test Scenario and execute the Rule service, It runs fine.

kie-container shows me the End point as 

http://host:port/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/container1

But I can't find how to pass parameters to the service using a Rest Client (Advanced Rest Client).

I send this Parameters with the Request and it gives me the following response.

> REQUEST

```
{
 "commands":[
   {
      "insert":{
         "out-identifier":"Customer",
         "return-object":"true",
         "object": {
           "example.si.Customer":{
             "time":3,
             "age":70,
             "gender":"MALE"
           }
         }
       }
   },
   {
      "fire-all-rules":""
   }
 ]
```

}

> HEADERS
>       X-KIE-ContentType: JSON
>       Accept: application/json
>       Content-Type: application/json
>       authorization: Basic a2llc2VydmVyOmtpZXNlcnZlcjEh
>
> RESPONSE

```
{
"type": "SUCCESS"
"msg": "Container sinterest5 successfully called."
"result": "{ "results" : [ { "key" : "", "value" : 0 }, { "key" : "Customer", "value" : {"example.si.Customer":{ "time" : 3, "age" : 70, "interest" : null, "gender" : "MALE", "rate" : null, "amount" : null }} } ], "facts" : [ { "key" : "Customer", "value" : {"org.drools.core.common.DefaultFactHandle":{ "external-form" : "0:5:695977235:695977235:5:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:example.si.Customer" }} } ] }"
}
```

And my Rule is..

```
 package Deciding_Rates;
```

//generated from Decision Table
import example.si.Customer;
function void interest(int time, int rate, int amount)
{System.out.println ( (time * rate * amount )/100 );System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());}
    lock-on-active true
// rule values at C15, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_15"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time< 5, Age>=65, Gender == "MALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(10)};
        System.out.println("Time < 5, Senior, Male");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C16, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_16"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time< 5, Age>=65, Gender == "FEMALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(11)};
        System.out.println("Time < 5, Senior, Female");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C17, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_17"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time< 5, Age<65, Gender == "MALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(8)};
        System.out.println("Time < 5, young, Male");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C18, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_18"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time< 5, Age<65, Gender == "FEMALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(9)};
        System.out.println("Time < 5, young, Female");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C19, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_19"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time >= 5, Age>=65, Gender == "MALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(12)};
        System.out.println("Time >= 5, Senior, Male");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C20, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_20"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time >= 5, Age>=65, Gender == "FEMALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(13)};
        System.out.println("Time >= 5, Senior, Female");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C21, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_21"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time >= 5, Age<65, Gender == "MALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(10)};
        System.out.println("Time >= 5, young, Male");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

// rule values at C22, header at C10
rule "DecidingRate_22"
    ruleflow-group "Rate"
    when
        $customer : Customer(Time >= 5, Age<65, Gender == "FEMALE")
    then
        modify($customer){setRate(11)};
        System.out.println("Time >= 5, young, Female");
        interest($customer.getTime(), $customer.getRate(), 100);
end

Am I doing anything wrong Here? Sysouts are not visible in server logs. I am not sure is my rules are getting fired or not.